# Solutions for inspecting text, audio and pictures for inappropriate content

Tags: filter

I'm working on a project where I want to get notified when inappropriate content (swearing, adult content, etc.) has been detected.

While I want it mostly for text data, I would be interested in this for audio files as well.

It obviously will be a commercial solution, but I couldn't find anything which offers these features.

It should support some form of integration (API if it's hosted, or an 'engine' sdk).

Does this really not exist?

Answer (score 0):

Could you write a Jquery or JS that will filter out these words after the page has loaded? It's a straightforward "`regexp`" (find/replace) and you can replace the words with asterisks `***` or something, or just white them out.

If you can do this on the server side, while comments from users for instance are being saved, the regexp is better implemented there.